Jackson deserialize XML to list of abstract item based on NodeTagName
I want to deserialize an XML with jackson.
I have an xml string like this:
"<items><RulesActivity/><StartActivity/><RulesActivity/></items>"

This is my deserialization class:
class Items {

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "items")
    private List<Item> activities;

    public Items() {}

    public List<Item> getActivities() {
      return activities;
    }

    public void setActivities(List<Item> activities) {
      this.activities = activities;
    }
  }

I have the abstract class "Item" and all the implementations for every type of node.
abstract class Item {}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "RulesActivity")
public class RulesActivity extends Item {}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "UserActivity")
public class UserActivity extends Item {}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "StartActivity")
public class StartActivity extends Item {}

I want for the tag RulesActivity to be parsed as an instance of the RulesActivity class and the tag UserActivity as an instance of the StartActivity class.
I want to read them in the same order as they are in the xml. How can I do this?
I tried to use the @JsonTypeInfo, but I have some results only with the "DEDUCTION" option. It's worked cause my activities have different attributes, but it's not assured to remain like this in the future.
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.DEDUCTION)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(value = UserActivity.class, name = "UserActivity"),
    @Type(value = RulesActivity.class, name = "RulesActivity")
})
abstract class Item {}

